# Migrating ScriptProcessorNode into AudioWorkletNode

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3, chrome-extension-manifest-v2, audio-capture

I am capturing audio in background now.
But the version was updated from Manifest v2 into Manifest v3.
I changed the way to capture audio in Manifest v3 because the audio capture in background.js was prevented in Manifest v3.
I used the old code but this warning doesn't disappear in console.
[image]
This is a class which is used to capture audio in Manifest v2 but I used this in Manifest v3 of chrome extension.

```
class Recorder {

    constructor(source, configs) {
        this.context = source.context;
        if (this.context.createScriptProcessor == null)
            this.context.createScriptProcessor = this.context.createJavaScriptNode;
        this.input = this.context.createGain();
        source.connect(this.input);
        this.buffer = [];
    }

    startRecording() {
        if (!this.isRecording()) {
            let numChannels = this.numChannels;
            let buffer = this.buffer;
            let worker = this.worker;
            this.processor = this.context.createScriptProcessor(
                this.options.bufferSize,
                this.numChannels, this.numChannels);
            this.input.connect(this.processor);
            this.processor.connect(this.context.destination);
            this.processor.onaudioprocess = function (event) {
                if (strRecordStatus === 'RECORDING') {
                                    ....
                }
            };
        }
    }
}
```

I try to remove this warning by migration from deprecated ScriptProcessorNode into AudioWorkletNode.
But I am not sure how to migrate this API in Manifest v3.
Looking forward to find out the way how to do it.

Comment: Judging by the error you use it in the content script, not in the background script, so the version of Manifest doesn't matter and you can use AudioWorkletNode as shown in the examples. In case you actually need it in the background script, the workaround is to do it inside the [offscreen document](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/offscreen/).